# How can I determine the MD5 digest of a given asset in the Rails asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, md5, asset-pipeline, handlebars.js

I'm writing a Javascript-rich application in a Ruby on Rails 3.1 project and using Handlebars for my JS templating framework. I'm trying to figure out a way to dynamically append the MD5 digest of an asset (generated during asset precompilation on production) to my  tags inside of my Handlebars template. I'm hoping that there's a hash with the asset path as the key and the MD5 digest as the value, but I haven't been able to find one.

An ideal solution would be passing the hash from Ruby into Javascript and defining a Handlebars helper that would automatically append the MD5 digest to the "src" attribute of the asset.

Has anybody attempted to do something similar? There must be a way to use Javascript templates in Rails and also reap the benefits of asset fingerprinting.

Comment: It is a default in the production env.[Asset-pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: What about using asset_path in your json response?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As someone mentioned in the comments, appending a hash to the asset paths is a default part of the asset pipeline.

> In production, Rails inserts an MD5 fingerprint into each filename so that the file is cached by the web browser

You can read more about fingerprinting in the asset pipeline **[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care)**. Rails uses [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) to compile assets. The fingerprinting comes as part of Sprockets process.

You can use Sprockets' `find_asset` method, passing in a logical path to your asset to get a `Sprockets::BundledAsset` instance. For example

```
[1] pry(main)> Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.js')
=> #<Sprockets::BundledAsset:0x3fe368ab8070 pathname="/Users/deefour/Sites/MyApp/app/assets/javascripts/application.js", mtime=2013-02-03 15:33:57 -0500, digest="ab07585c8c7b5329878b1c51ed68831e">
```

You can call `digest_path` on this object to get it's `MD5` sum appended to the asset.

```
[1] pry(main)> Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.js').digest_path
=> "application-ab07585c8c7b5329878b1c51ed68831e.js"
```

With this knowledge you can easily create a helper to return the `digest_path` for any asset in your application, and call this helper from within your `.js.erb` files.

Comment: The find_asset method is exactly what I was looking for and could not find. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why is the digest path different than the one in the actual file name?

Comment: can we overhide fingerprint?

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but it seems that nowadays you can use `assets_manifest`:

`Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets["application.css"]
=> "application-46ae33e78e504ff295219f41d63c79719d062e48dc0c07bd9b6f7bcad72c6636.css"`

More discussion here: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/311