# How to get asset version string from the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I'm adding a really simple caching script (JavaScript) to a rails project, and need to get the rails asset version number in order to make the two work together nicely. I can't however find out how to get the versioning string for use.

I need to update the two strings below (in a JS file) with the relevant version string from rails. How can I get this information.

```
var urlsToCache = [
    '/css/main.css',
    '/javascript/application.js'
];
```

I'm aware that I may need to export the version string as JSON, building the array from that JSON within my JavaScript file.

Any help, or a point in the right direction, is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass it in the json from the server.

To actually get the fingerprint, you can call digest_path on an asset to get it's MD5 sum appended value. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719788/how-can-i-determine-the-md5-digest-of-a-given-asset-in-the-rails-asset-pipeline), which the following snippet is taken from:

```
[1] pry(main)> Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.js').digest_path
=> "application-ab07585c8c7b5329878b1c51ed68831e.js"
```

Comment: `digest_path` was just what I was looking for. Thank you :)