# Rails: How to serve asset pipeline (just js) through a regular route?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm developing a project that consists in both a chrome extension and a spa. And, here is my problem: I have a lot of javascript that is common to both parts, what I'd like to do is:

1. Serve the SPA through the regular asset pipeline (application.js)
2. Serve common javascript to be consumed by the chrome extension with a regular route. (Say `example.com/chrome-extension/application.js`).

Ideally this response (2) would have both data (from ruby) and the regular result of an asset pipeline.

File: `app/views/chrome-extension/application.js.erb`

  `` Global.data = { somekey: '<%= @some_value %>' }
  # append, inline, the same results that I'd get from `application.js` or, even better, from a second asset pipeline `chrome-extension.js`" ``

Any thoughts? :D

Answer (score 0):

Found it :)

`Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.js').to_s` is what I was looking for.

[Found in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421204/how-to-get-asset-version-string-from-the-asset-pipeline)

FYI I created two different files

`application.js`

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree lib <- Magic here
//= require_tree spa
//= require index
```

`lib.js` (common to spa and chrome-extension)

```
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./resources
//= require_tree ./whatever
```