# asset_path (with fingerprint) from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I develop a rails app with exercises (for kids with learning difficulties in math). The interactive part of the exercises is written in javascript. I store each exercise in a database. The javascript contains

```
<%= asset_path('to_images') %>
```

I can read the scripts into the controller and write the content to a partial, but I think it would be better to capture the scripts in a variable, like:

```
@animation = exercise.animation
```

where any code containing <%= asset_path(...) %> would be replaced with the correct fingerprinted route to the asset.

Here is an example of a code snippet in exercise.animation:

```
$("#hundred_square td").css({
    backgroundImage: 'url(<%= asset_path("exercises/shapes/circles/circle_open_black_48.png") %>)',
    backgroundSize: "2vw",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "center"
});
```

I have already tried to

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
```

and

```
self.animation.gsub(/\<\%\=\s*asset_path\((.+)\)\s*\%\>/) do |match|
  address = $1
  puts "#{address}"
       =>  "exercises/shapes/circles/circle_open_black_48.png"
  puts "#{asset_path(address)}"
       =>  /"exercises/shapes/circles/circle_open_black_48.png"
  puts "#{ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(address)}"
       =>  /"exercises/shapes/circles/circle_open_black_48.png"
end
```

do not produce the result I need.
Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Are you are trying to execute Ruby ERB within Javascript?

Comment: Why trying? In .erb files the ruby code is handled first. If I read the javascript code (including ruby code) into the controller and then write it into a partial, all works beautifully.

Comment: I see, so you're using a `js.erb` file.  Is your problem that this ERB is not correctly being parsed into an asset path within the view, or is it that you can't access the helper method within your Model?

Comment: Thanks Kelseydh. I am not using a js.erb file in this case. I am storing the javascript code in the database (with its exercise). When I read that code, I would like to have a way to have the controller (or even better the model) deal with the code as if it was a template, to replace the <%= ... %> code (which I can do) and then make it into a route including the fingerprint. (See the last 2 paragraphs, from "I have already tried to") - I need a result like: 'url(/assets/exercises/shapes/circles/circle_open_black_48-d6e60117aaf82eb468c535ce7705abced4008ddda9010adf30b0c030ad568632.png)'

Comment: Just as an aside, if any of the javascript you are storing in the database contains the results of user input I would advise against storing JS in your database as it will make your app susceptible to XSS attacks. (e.g. If someone publicly can execute `alert("pwned")` from the JS you may have an issue )

Comment: I know - do you have any ideas how to solve my problem?

Comment: Just to be clear, can you confirm you can successfully get the fingerprint for these assets when you call `asset_path` from within the view? If not, get fingerprint working there first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to fetch the MD5 fingerprint value is to use Sprockets' `find_asset` method, passing in a logical path to your asset to get a `Sprockets::BundledAsset` instance. For example

```
[1] pry(main)> Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.js')
=> #<Sprockets::BundledAsset:0x3fe368ab8070 pathname="/Users/deefour/Sites/MyApp/app/assets/javascripts/application.js", mtime=2013-02-03 15:33:57 -0500, digest="ab07585c8c7b5329878b1c51ed68831e">
```

You can call `digest_path` on this object to get it's `MD5` sum appended to the asset.

```
[1] pry(main)> Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.js').digest_path
=> "application-ab07585c8c7b5329878b1c51ed68831e.js"
```

With this knowledge you can create a helper to return the `digest_path` for any asset in your application, call this helper from within your `.js.erb` files or from within your model.

See [this answer for more details on this approach.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14720284/3448554)